# ResourcesPlugin - Is it possible to change workspace?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

When launching a plugin, I have some code that calls

```
getWorkspace()
```

method of class ResourcesPlugin. This returns the current workspace. However, is it possible to specify a workspace instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only one workspace can be loaded in Eclipse at a time. There is no facilities to gain programmatic access to another workspace. You have to restart Eclipse with that workspace to gain access to it.

Comment: The switch workspace menu restarts most of the Eclipse in order to change the workspace.

Comment: But not the whole. It is **not** a restart. Other way there would be no need in the command "switch workspace". So, the last sentence of your answer is wrong.

Comment: Hardly. When invoking switch workspace, the only thing that isn't restarted is the core JVM. Everything that people know as Eclipse is restarted. The only reason this command exists is to save the user a few clicks. It is of no use to a plugin writer as a way to access content from multiple workspaces simultaneously. Any plugin invoking switch workspace command will itself be rebooted.